# Why is git so slow with large files?

Tags: git

I was trying to use git to manage my pictures (backup / take snapshots). The entire library is several GB. Most of the files are JPGs of 2-3M. When I was adding the files into repository, it seemed to be taking several days. CPU utilization was always near 100%.

Is there a reason why git should be slow on large files?

p.s. I know git was not designed for this.

Answer (score 7):

Git by default compresses files. JPEGs by default are already compressed. It's not that it's large files, it's that it's compressed files.

You'll notice the same effect adding ZIP files to a git repository.

EDIT: There is an interesting thread on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102053/git-pull-without-remotely-compressing-objects about compression.

Comment: How can I tell git not to compress files? I don't necessarily need space efficiency. I want it to be as fast as possible. Thanks!

Comment: There's a host of switches you can play with in `git config`, including `core.compression` and `pack.window`. Seeing as I've never actually tried running git without compression, YMMV. Please post what you discovered, to help us all learn from your experience.

Comment: @Eroen, you make a good point. I've voted your comment up.

Comment: Git also makes (and checks) a sha1 hash of every file every time it uses it, that can take some time too for large files.

Comment: @Eroen, do you know how long that SHA-1 hash takes? I'd wonder if it's significant, given 2MB files. Perhaps on hundreds.

Comment: @RandolphWest: Good, but wrong. zlib compression can be turned off by `$ git set core.compression 0`. sha1 is tens of MiB per second, but they might interfere badly with low memory conditions.