# Using git to take over the management of half synchronized text file directories

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sync, git

This is a problem that hard to describe (and of course hard to search for answer), the closest that I found is
[Moving two existing already-synced directory trees to git annex](https://superuser.com/questions/564381/moving-two-existing-already-synced-directory-trees-to-git-annex)

I have two copies of my document text files, one on a desktop Linux machine, one on a laptop. Previously, I run `rsync` periodically to keep these files in sync both ways. I'd now like to move management of this problem to `git`, but was wondering what the cleanest way to start would be.

I've put files on my desktop into a remote `git` server, following the instructions on the web. That was fine. Now the problem to me is on the laptop side. I.e., I already have a half synced files and folders on my laptop, and I don't think the commonly suggested `git clone` would be the proper answer to my situation, would it?

Say that the files and folders on my laptop are already out of sync with my desktop's, **both ways**. What would the proper steps to get my document text files back in sync using `git` with my already-setup remote `git` repo?

Comment: I'd suggest using `unison`: it is specifically designed for two-way (or multi-host) synchronization.

Comment: Thanks, the `unison` is actually what I've been using, but now prefer `git`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer as to why using git for syncing isn't a good idea.

Here is a test case that shows how to sync git with two already populated directories.

```
cd /tmp
mkdir foo
cd foo
git init
echo "hello" > README.md
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git remote add origin git@github.com:<myUser>/test.git
git push -u origin master
```

At this point I have a local git repo which is synchronized  with my git server. 
I will now create a new copy of the REDME.md file as if it had been rsyn-ed to another machine

```
cd /tmp
mkdir bar
cd bar
git init
echo "hello" > README.md
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git remote add origin git@github.com:<myUser>/test.git
git push -u origin master
```

Because bar is behind master, I am unable to push.

```
To git@github.com:<myUser>/test.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:<myUser>/test.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I tried doing a git pull. Git merged the repo's but did not download the file, because it already exists locally.

> git pull origin master From github.com:/test  * branch
>   master     -> FETCH_HEAD Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.

You must also always remember to do a git pull before changing any files on each system, otherwise you will get conflicts that need to be resolved.

Comment: I was trying to avoid using `git pull` to pull in everything since I've already get most of them in sync. If the latest updated version is always on one side (i.e., not on both), do I still need this approach? If there are updates happened to the same file on both side, wouldn't I have to resolve the conflicts any way?

Comment: @xpt Git only sync's files that have changed between local and origin. I just ran a test to prove this. I am going to modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can git clone to your laptop, then copy the existing files in your laptop over the working copy. You'll then can composed a merged file by checking the diffs, possibly restoring the deleted lines that you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem like using git as a synchronization mediator would be the perfect solution. I would recommend you steer clear from using git as a synchronization tool for the following reasons.

Git was not ever intended to work in this way.

[Git performs slowly with large files](https://superuser.com/questions/406907/why-is-git-so-slow-with-large-files) ([2](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota))

[Git does not sync empty folders](http://to.pm.org/presentations/2010-09/git-based-backup.pdf)

[Git does not track file system metadata](http://to.pm.org/presentations/2010-09/git-based-backup.pdf)

[Git does not track other git projects (any folder with a .git folder inside it)](http://to.pm.org/presentations/2010-09/git-based-backup.pdf)

A quote from githubs website

> Though it sounds like Git would make an amazing backup tool, Git really doesn't work out well for backups over the long term

https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota

If you've ever worked with a repo that has thousands of commits, git gets very slow. Dropbox or rsync are going to be the better tool for the job.